# Change string in javascript to object

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have this code:

```
locales = __.each results, (value, index, list) ->
  locale = value.split("-")[0] # gives me type of string "ru"
  console.log typeof locale
  console.log cldr.extractLanguageDisplayNames(locale).ru
  console.log  cldr.extractLanguageDisplayNames(locale).locale
```

So this `console.log cldr.extractLanguageDisplayNames(locale).ru` works and returns 'русский', but for `console.log  cldr.extractLanguageDisplayNames(locale).locale` I get `undefined`.

Basically I would like to generate the country names based on the locales folders.

Answer (score 1):

ok i figured it out, it should be:

`console.log  cldr.extractLanguageDisplayNames(locale)[locale]`